# Using several predictors from one origin to run a zero inflated negative binomial regression

Tags: regression

I have a dataset like this image[image] and I want to run a zero inflated negative binomial (ZINB) regression in Stata (Outcome: crime rate). In 3 age group variables I have the percent of population in each city (for example 20% of city "a" population is in age 0-20 group.

Is it true to include all of the 3 age group variables in the ZINB considering they are from the same origin and value of 2 group can estimate the 3rd one?